# How to calculate odds ratio per unit decrease of continuous variable

Tags: r, logistic, continuous-data, odds-ratio

I have a logistic regression model obtained in R comparing association between two index diagnoses (0 or 1) with `Age` (continuous) + `Sex` (Factor) + `Renal.Fn` (continuous). My variable of interest is `Renal.Fn`.

```
 model <- glm(diagnosis ~ Age + Sex + Renal.Fn, data = data, family = "binomial")
```

Currently to obtain Odds Ratio:

```
exp(coef(model))[4]       # Renal.Fn 0.9884664
exp(confint(model))[[4]]  # Renal.Fn 0.9848022 0.9920815
```

My interpretation: Per unit increase in renal function the odds of diagnosis of interest reduces.

I wish to demonstrate the opposite.  For example: Per unit decrease in renal function, the odds of diagnosis increases.

Question:

1. Is it correct to take `1 / exp(coef)` to derive the odds per unit decrease?
2. Is it subsequently correct to take `1/exp(coef) ^10` to derive odds per ten unit decrease?

Comment: So $\log{\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}}=\alpha+A+S+R.Fn$, right? What you usually do is to use $\frac{e^{...+R.Fn(x+1)}}{1+e^{...+R.Fn(x+1)}}=e^{R.Fn}\frac{e^{...+R.Fn(x)}}{1+e^{...+R.Fn(x)}}$. Now just put $x-1$ instead of $x+1$, which will indeed give you $e^{-R.Fn}$.

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze Thanks, thats right. So essentially I can take 1 / 0.9884664 to derive the odds ratio per unit reduction? Thanks for the detailed formula, this is the problem with R as its all hidden..

Comment: Yes, that's it. You can repeat the same for your bullet point #2 :)

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze thanks very much, appreciate the assistance