# glm output interpretation help

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I am using the residuals from a linear mixed effect model from the below formula ( having family structure as a random effect as the individuals are related.

```
 mod<- lmer(Genes ~ Age + Gender + Medication + (1|Familystructure)
 
 summary(mod)$res
```

I am then using these residuals in a glm to determine the association between the genes and the odds of disease

```
res<-glm(Disease ~ residuals, family=binomial)
```

If I am understanding this correctly- As an example, for gene 1, the odds ratio is 0.58, which shows that per unit increase in gene 1 there is a 58 % reduced odds of developing the disease.

```
 Logit odds = -0.49775
 Exp(logit odds) = 0.60
 Lower 95% CI= 0.3984
 Upper 95% CI= 0.927928
```

I know when running an lmer to look at how these genes change as a response to disease that this gene 1 significantly reduces in disease vs control, which is in accordance with the fact that an increase results in less of a likelihood of disease.

Could anybody advise please as to whether I can only infer that a unit decrease of this gene would result in an increased odds of disease? I was unsure whether exp(0.49775) ( changing the sign of the logit odds), yielding an odds of 1.645, corresponds to this?

Comment: Could you add a reference describing this approach?

Comment: @MichaelM Please could you clarify what for ( the use of the residuals from lmer as a predictor in the glm?). If there may be any problems using this approach, please also comment if possible.

Answer (score 0):

[How to calculate odds ratio per unit decrease of continuous variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210914/how-to-calculate-odds-ratio-per-unit-decrease-of-continuous-variable)

This link explains mathematically how this can be done in terms of working out the odds ratio per unit decrease by doing 1/exp(coef), which gets the same as exp(+ve logitodds).